# ionic pages issue on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5JNk.png)

Just like the image shows. When I scroll my page from bottom to top, the page shows a white bar.
How can I solve this? Is there anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding the related commands, code snippets or configuration infos... Otherwise your issue might be classified as off-topic as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Hi, lloyd. It is a little difficult for me to describe it. I'm not sure if you have seen my picture uploaded. In a word, the question is that the ionic page scrolls over the limit , then it shows a part of white screen on iOS, but it runs normal on Android.

Comment: issue is fixed by add <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" /> in the config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed by adding

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

in the config.xml